# I want my Eclipse Java sockets client to receive a variable number or packets

Tags: java, sockets, client

I am writing a client in Java. It sends a message based on keyboard input, and receives a reply. It uses Java socket readline().  The problem I have is that my server may sent a variable number of response lines, so I don't know how many lines to try to read, and the responses may be from the previous packet.   My solution  would be to delay 100 ms and then poll to see what came back, and then receive however many packets are there in response, but I don't see a poll() function.  I have a background in C, and use the poll function for this sort of thing - but I don't see a poll function available in Java.  Can someone suggest a solution to this problem of receiving an unknown number of packets or lines?

Below is the code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FirstCommunications {
    
private Socket socket = null;
private DataInputStream keyboardinput = null;
private DataOutputStream out = null;
    
private DataInputStream sr = null;  // server response
    
public FirstCommunications(String address, int port)
{
        
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("Connected\n");
            
        keyboardinput = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        sr = new  DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException u)   {
        System.out.println(u);
    }
    catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    String someStuff = "Try it tomorrow \n";
    try {
        while(!someStuff.equals("MoveOn")) {
            //someStuff = keyboardinput.readLine();
            String message = sr.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("Catching it");
    }
        
        
        
    while(!someStuff.equals("NoMoreStuff")) {
        try {
            someStuff = keyboardinput.readLine();
            //someStuff = "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM";
            out.writeUTF(someStuff);
                
            String message = sr.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
        
    try {
        keyboardinput.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
        
        

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Some text \n some more text");


    FirstCommunications firstCommunications = new FirstCommunications ("192.168.1.218", 8888);
}
```

}

Comment: In the server, either send the number of lines before sending the lines or send a terminator line (for example, an empty line) after sending the lines.

Comment: Dear revered - Thanks ! Neat idea - I tried the pack of length zero, but that was ignored by readLine() - however, I can make a packet  with just Done or something . . . thanks again  Paul